# Oracle SYS_GUID does not change

Tags: oracle, guid

I have an Oracle project that would be a good fit for using GUIDs as a key. I found the following snippet

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
FOR indx IN 1 .. 5
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( SYS_GUID );
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

From http://feuerthoughts.blogspot.com/2006/02/watch-out-for-sequential-oracle-guids.html

When I run it against my database (I tried it on versions 10g and version 11) I get output like

```
64FE4083D6BA7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BB7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BC7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BD7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BE7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
```

I.e. the value never changes! Is there something I have to do to set this up to work as expected?

Edit: I am not very observant - the GUIDs are changing, but it looks like I am suffering from the sequential GUID problem that the link above is talking about.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seems OK. From the description:

> SYS_GUID generates and returns a
>   globally unique identifier (RAW value)
>   made up of 16 bytes. On most
>   platforms, the generated identifier
>   consists of a host identifier, a
>   process or thread identifier of the
>   process or thread invoking the
>   function, and a **nonrepeating** value
>   (sequence of bytes) for that process
>   or thread.

From your example:

```
64FE4083D6BA7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BB7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BC7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BD7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BE7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
```

Nobody mentioned anything about the distribution of these GUID values. They should be nonrepeating and they are. Unless you get exactly the same output every time.

Comment: Good eyes! I think this is the problem that the think I posted is talking about though.

Answer (score 21):

The value does change....

```
           *
64FE4083D6BA7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BB7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BC7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BD7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
64FE4083D6BE7CB4E0400F0A0E0A18B0
           *
```

Comment: :-)   We've all been there.... you can stare at something for an hour and not spot something that a colleague then spots in 5 seconds.

Comment: I came here for the exact same reason - very subtle!